# How to hide "code actions" from lsp-ui sidebar?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp-ui

[image]

Hi,
I want to hide "code actions" which is recommended by lsp-mode from lsp-ui sidebar.

How can I do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set the variable lsp-ui-sideline-show-code-actions to nil

```
(setq lsp-ui-sideline-show-code-actions nil)
```